# No connection could be made

Tags: php, database

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Here is my code.

```
    //$db = 'htdocs\as4.mdb';

    //$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');

    mysql_connect('htdocs\as4.mdb');
    mysql_select_db('vendor');

    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vendor WHERE vendorName like '%search%' OR 
                address like '%search%' or
                city like '%search%' or
                provState like '%search%' or
                country like '%search%'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die (mysql_error());

    $number = mysql_num_rows($result);
   // <h3>$number of results found search for "$search"</h3>

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $vendorName = $row['vendorName'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $provState = $row['provState'];
        $country = $row['country'];
    }


?>
```

I'm trying to connect to the database and through a search textbox find a certain keyword and display results with anything that has to do with the key word, for example if I type in Canada I would like to see the results of all the people in Canada. I tried to do it through new COM('ADODB.Connection') as you can see it commented out, but couldn't figure out exactly how.

What if I wanted to use something like this to search the database?

```
$db = 'htdocs\database\database.mdb';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Vendor";

//to make this work, you need to add
//extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
//to your php.ini file. Put it with the other
//extension=
//values towards the bottom of the file (around line number 1050)
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');

if(!$conn)
{
    echo "Database unreachable";
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "Success!<hr />";

    try
    {
        $conn -> Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=$db");
        $rs = $conn->Execute($sql);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "<br />";
        exit();
    }

    while(!$rs->EOF)
    {
        For($i = 0; $i < ($rs->Fields->Count); $i++)
        {
            echo $rs->Fields[$i]->Value;
            echo " ";
        }
        echo "<br />";
        $rs->MoveNext();
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend using PDO, and not MySQL https://github.com/yazinsai/php-pdo-mysql

Comment: check if your database requires a password or other such data

Comment: It looks like you're trying to connect to a SQL-T database, you may need to check which ports are open on the server you're trying to connect to.. and whether it has remote access enabled (for the user account accessing the database). Check whether you can connect to it with a Client Side Application like [HediSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).